# Getting child div columns to inherit height of the tallest column / fill entire parent height

Tags: css

Site can be seen here: http://storagestaging.com/pricing/

Question is with regards to the four column pricing grid.

I have a four column pricing grid.  Each column has a different height (due to more or less content).  I'd like to get all four columns to fill the entire length of the tallest column / fill the entire parent div.

I've tried display: table and display:table-cell, and adding height=100% to parent and child divs.  Sometimes I get closer, sometimes I just make it worse.  Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a perfectly valid reason to use a table. A JS solution is easy to make, but I don't see a reason for one

Comment: You need to specify 100% height for all parent elements up to `html` element in order to get them all to spread 100% (unless you use static heights)

Answer (score 0):

In case you do decide to use divs, a JS (this is a jQuery version, if you need vanilla JS lemme know) solution is possible:

```
var max = 0;
$('.myDiv').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > max)
        max = $(this).height();
});
$('.myDiv').css('height', max + ' px');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  I'm not familiar with jQuery and I don't have any on the site so I'm going to try to do it without it.  But I may try this anyway!

Comment: I just set the column height manually as well.  This should work for now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this css, just the height of the parent div would need to be a fixed value.

[See this example here](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/hvolA)

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner a"></div>
  <div class="inner b"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer{
  background: #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.inner{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;

}

.a{
  background-color: green;
}

.b{
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this.  I added a height to the parent div and I'm getting much closer.  But now there seems to be some imaginary padding at the bottom of each column.

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill my request I just manually set the hight of the parent and child sections.